# Suppress launch logging in React Native app

Tags: react-native, expo

Is there any way to suppress this from the log every time I launch my expo app:

```
Running application "main" with appParams: {"rootTag":171,"initialProps":{"exp":{"manifest":{"slug":"F8-Elements","debuggerHost":"192.168.1.5:19001","packagerOpts":{"lanType":"ip","urlRandomness":"7i-wxv","hostType":"lan","dev":true,"minify":false},"bundleUrl":"http://xxx.xxx.x:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%MyComputer%2FDevelopment%2FQMG-local%2FF8-Elements%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js","icon":"./assets/images/icon.png","isVerified":true,"name":"F8 Elements React Native","xde":true,"version":"1.0.0","iconUrl":"http://xxx.xxx.x:19001/assets/./assets/images/icon.png","hostUri":"xxx.xxx.x.5:19000","id":"@tuzmusic/F8-Elements","updates":{"fallbackToCacheTimeout":0},"orientation":"portrait","sdkVersion":"32.0.0","loadedFromCache":false,"logUrl":"http://xxx.xxx.x.5:19000/logs","env":{},"ios":{"supportsTablet":true},"platforms":["ios","android"],"assetBundlePatterns":["**/*"],"privacy":"public","mainModuleName":"node_modules/expo/AppEntry","developer":{"projectRoot":"/Users/MyComputer/Development/QMG-local/F8-Elements","tool":"expo-cli"},"splash":{"resizeMode":"contain","backgroundColor":"#ffffff","image":"./assets/images/splash.png","imageUrl":"http://192.168.1.5:19001/assets/./assets/images/splash.png"}},"appOwnership":"expo","initialUri":"exp://xxx.xxx.x.5:19000","shell":0}}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
```

It's obviously part of the expo library or something, but is there maybe something I can write in my `package.json` to turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard message [emitted here by React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/e10f7788c4ebf29d96594f9753264bdf6146f0cf/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js#L185), not by Expo. It doesn't seem you can turn it off, other than increasing the default log level to be above "info".

Comment: Which would then silence any `console.log` statements I've put in my own code, right?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I assume so yeah

Comment: give it a try 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62932501/7980271